# Change product special price only for current session

Tags: magento

Is it possible to set product special price for current session? because i have to set product special price if my custom condition is satisfied?is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What? Change special price per customer session? Not possible. Special price is a product attribute and is a global value (well scoped to store level), so it can't be changed within the customer session easily. Wouldn't want to even attempt doing so! Can't you simply use built in promo rules and conditions to achieve discount based upon criterias and mod product view template to show accordingly.

Comment: @AshleySwatton actually i am in wrong direction thanks for guide to right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your objective?

1. Special price is not dependent on customer group.
2. If there is some specific custom condition that can be defined by catalog rules then use catalog rules.
3. Else you need to create your custom module and modify product price calculation under specific condition(bit complex)

Comment: i create extension to achieve this similar goal thanks..for comment